# How do I override Apple Watch back button to pop to root controller

Tags: swift, apple-watch

Im trying to push multiple WKInterfaceControllers

Route: A -> B -> C -> D

I want the controller D to have a back button of A.

How do I override the top left back button of the watch so I can go back to the root controller?

I dont know how to access the button or override the method. All I know is that the code below pops back to the root.

```
self.popToRootController();
```

Answer (score 2):

From everyone I have spoken to, this is not possible at this time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible but you can do it with this written under a button IBAction
 `[self pushControllerWithName:@"D" context:nil];`